# Error when passing data from one view controller to the other

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser, swift2

I'm currently making an rss feed reader in swift 2 and I'm having a hard time trying to pass the url from my tableview to my web view. When I print my url in the tableviewcontroller it adds (optional) in front of the url. However when it has passed into my webviewcontroller it has no (optional) inf front of it. This makes me worry over the fact that something has gone wrong on the way.

tableviewcontroller passing the url to the webviewcontroller:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){


        let webVC = WebViewController()
        webVC.entryUrl = entriesArray[indexPath.row]["link"]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webVC, animated: true)
        print(entriesArray[indexPath.row]["link"])


}
```

webviewcontroller receiving the data and trying to use it:

```
    var entryUrl:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(entryUrl)

    if entryUrl != nil {
    print(entryUrl)
    let requesturl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: entryUrl)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl!)

    web.loadRequest(request)

    }
    loadAddressURL()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}


func loadAddressURL() {
    if let requestURL = NSURL(string: entryUrl) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        web?.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

I get an error on the line:

```
loadAddressURL()
```

saying:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on dispatch_semaphore_dispose
```

From the tableviewcontroller the log prints:
Optional("http://www.google.com/")

But from the webviewcontroller the log just prints:
http://www.google.com/

and after that:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why won't this work and why is the the url not an optional anymore in the webviewcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line of code to declare object of view Controller as below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){


    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let webVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as! WebViewController

    webVC.entryUrl = entriesArray[indexPath.row]["link"]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webVC, animated: true)
    print(entriesArray[indexPath.row]["link"])
  }
```

Dont forgot to add indetifier of viewController in storyBoard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a thousand times thank you. You have no idea how thankful I am for this. You have saved me from weeks of headache and sleepless nights. This solve my problem perfectly, thank you.